# Why does cnosdb cluster failed to initialize the default tenants?

Tags: cnosdb

I'm trying to run CnosDB cluster mode on my PC, but it crushed on start and throw an error: `make dbms: Meta { source: TenantNotFound { tenant: "cnosdb" } }`, seems failed initializing the default tenant.

> Version: cnosdb 2.3.0, revision f4b52408171467c5ea2b2f75480deecc6f6ad733

#### Configurations

I have these two configurations:

##### Node - meta_1

Config for meta node:

- service-addr: 127.0.0.1:8901

```ini
id = 1
host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 8901

snapshot_path = "/tmp/meta_1/snapshot"
journal_path = "/tmp/meta_1/journal"
snapshot_per_events = 500

[log]
level = "info"
path = "/tmp/meta_1/logs"

[meta_init]
cluster_name = "meta_1"
admin_user = "root"
system_tenant = "cnosdb"
default_database = ["public", "usage_schema"]

[heartbeat]
heartbeat_recheck_interval = 300
heartbeat_expired_interval = 600
```

##### Node - data_1

Config for data node:

- service-addr: 127.0.0.1:8912

```ini
host = '127.0.0.1'

[cluster]
name = 'data_1'
http_listen_port = 8912
grpc_listen_port = 8913
flight_rpc_listen_port = 8914
tcp_listen_port = 8915
meta_service_addr = ['127.0.0.1:8901']

[node_basic]
node_id = 1
cold_data_server = false
store_metrics = true

[deployment]
mode = 'query_tskv'
[query]
[storage]
path = '/tmp/data_1/data'
[wal]
path = '/tmp/data_1/wal'
[cache]
[log]
level = 'info'
path = '/tmp/data_1/wal'
[security]
[hinted_off]
[heartbeat]
```

#### Commands and outputs

```
## Clean
$ rm -rf /tmp/test/*

## Run `cnosdb-meta`
$ cnosdb-meta --config ./meta_1.toml
.........

## Init cnosdb-meta as a cluster
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8901/init -d '{}'
{"Ok":null}

## Run `cnosdb`
$ cnosdb run --config data_1.toml
.........
2023-05-29T00:36:19.264002000+08:00  INFO tskv::wal: WAL '1' starts write
2023-05-29T00:36:19.264278000+08:00  WARN tskv::wal: Recover: reading wal from seq '0'
2023-05-29T00:36:19.264431000+08:00  INFO tskv::kvcore: Job 'WAL' starting.
2023-05-29T00:36:19.264463000+08:00  INFO tskv::kvcore: Flush task handler started
2023-05-29T00:36:19.264510000+08:00  INFO tskv::kvcore: Job 'WAL' started.
2023-05-29T00:36:19.264742000+08:00  INFO tskv::kvcore: Summary task handler started
The application panicked (crashed).
Message:  make dbms: Meta { source: TenantNotFound { tenant: "cnosdb" } }
Location: main/src/server.rs:246

  ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ BACKTRACE ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
                                ⋮ 10 frames hidden ⋮
  11: cnosdb::server::ServiceBuilder::create_dbms::{{closure}}::h1aef1bae443f563d
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  12: cnosdb::server::ServiceBuilder::build_query_storage::{{closure}}::h778497860af930a7
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  13: cnosdb::main::{{closure}}::hd08bd0324e3b1f23
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  14: cnosdb::main::h4f1efcc4db9ef8ea
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  15: std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace::hf3cbd67dc5a868f8
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  16: std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}::h76d82e46c7eb707c
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  17: std::rt::lang_start_internal::h672762ded3eb0218
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  18: _main<unknown>
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
```

I‘ve just checked the configurations and i've made sure that the `meta_1` listens on `127.0.0.1:8901` and, the  `data_1` is connecting to `127.0.0.1:8901`, but I'm puzzled by the output messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the configuration file of datanoe, ensure that the name in both [cluster] section with name='data_1' and [meta_init] section with cluster_name="meta_1" are the same. Otherwise, it will consider them as two separate clusters.

Comment: It works well when I have only edited `data_1.toml` to set `cluster.name = meta_1` and the cluster works well. But, if I only edited `meta_1.toml` to set `meta_init.cluster_name = data_1` then node data_1 crushed with message: `Message:  called Result::unwrap() on an Err value: MetaClientErr { msg: "error occur on remote peer 0: has to forward request to: None, None" }`.